# Questions about unipotent matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, matrices

I'm reading Lang's *Algebra*. There is an example on page 19.

Let $k$ be a field. Let $I$ be the unit $n\times n$ matrix, let $N$ be the additive group of matrices which are zero on and below the diagonal. Let $U_r=I+N^r$. Then prove that $U_{r+1}$ is a normal subgroup of $U_r$, and the factor group is isomorphic to the additive group $k^{n-r}$.

I want to check this statement by direct computation, but it seems complicated. Can you give me some suggestions? Since I'm a beginner, I want some linear algebra level explanation. Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a hint, $N^2$ consists of matrices in $N$ that are zero on the diagonal above the main diagonal, $N^3$ are those zero on the two diagonals above the main diagonal, etc.

Comment: i know this fact,following Alexander's advice,with more carefully calculation,all properties can be checked.Thanks any way!

Answer (score 0):

As the hint suggests, the matrices in $N^2$ are zero on the diagonal above the main diagonal and the matrices in $N^r$ are zero on $r$ diagonals above the main diagonal. Notice that any $m \in N$ has the property that $m^{n-1}=0$. Thus, such matrices are called nilpotent.

If $m,m' \in N^{r+1}$, then $(I+m)(I+m')=I^2+mI+Im'+mm'=I+m+m'+mm' \in U_{r+1}$. This shows that such elements are closed under multiplication. Try to show the other properties you need in a similar way. There may be a better way but one approach to dealing with inverses is probably to think about characteristic polynomials. Such matrices will all have characteristic polynomial $(t-1)^n$ and so for example if $m \in U_r$ and we let $n=2$,   then (by Cayley-Hamilton) $n^2-2n+1=0$ so that $2-n=n^{-1}$.

Comment: With your helpful suggestions i have solved this problem.Your idea on dealing with inverses works.i'm so happy!Thanks very much!You are great!

Comment: You're welcome!